# pagination using javacript remoting

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting, pagination

Kindly let me know what is wrong in the below code.Records are not getting displayed. I am not that much strong in javascript.
vf page:----

```
    <apex:page controller="javascriptremoting" >
<script>
    var current_page = 1;
var records_per_page = 2;
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
    '{!$RemoteAction.javascriptremoting.loadaccs}',
    function(result, event){
        var objJson =[];
        var names = [];
        var phone = [];
        // var index ="vineet";
        // if (event.status) {
            console.log (result);
         for(index in result){
                // if( result.hasOwnProperty(keyName ) ) {   
             objJson.push(index);
             //  names =names+ result[index].Name + '<br/>';
             //  phone =phone + result[index].Phone + '<br/>';
                //   }

            }
        //document.getElementById('ot').innerHTML = names;
        // document.getElementById('ph').innerHTML = phone;

        // }
    }, 
    {escape: true}
);
 function prevPage()
{
    if (current_page > 1) {
        current_page--;
        changePage(current_page);
    }
}

function nextPage()
{
    if (current_page < numPages()) {
        current_page++;
        changePage(current_page);
    }
}

function changePage(page)
{
    var btn_next = document.getElementById("btn_next");
    var btn_prev = document.getElementById("btn_prev");
    var listing_table = document.getElementById("listingTable");
    var page_span = document.getElementById("page");

    // Validate page
    if (page < 1) page = 1;
    if (page > numPages()) page = numPages();

    listing_table.innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = (page-1) * records_per_page; i < (page * records_per_page); i++) {
        listing_table.innerHTML += objJson[i].adName + "<br>";
    }
    page_span.innerHTML = page;

    if (page == 1) {
        btn_prev.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        btn_prev.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    if (page == numPages()) {
        btn_next.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        btn_next.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}

function numPages()
{
    return Math.ceil(objJson.length / records_per_page);
}

window.onload = function() {
    changePage(1);
};


    </script>



<html>
    <div id="listingTable"></div>
<a href="javascript:prevPage()" id="btn_prev">Prev</a>
<a href="javascript:nextPage()" id="btn_next">Next</a>
page: <span id="page"></span>

 </html>




</apex:page>
```

apex class code:-

```
public class javascriptremoting {
  @remoteAction
    public static List<Account> loadaccs(){

        return [select Id,Name,Phone from Account where Phone !=null];

        }
        }
```

Comment: why you are using javascript? pagination can easily be handled through StandardSetController

Comment: @Santanu Boral. Actually sir pagination using JavaScript loads page faster because JavaScript is client side. Also, JavaScript remoting does not count against view state. So, this the current requirement. I recognize u ,have gone through some of your blogs.

Comment: @vineet did you find a better way ?